# I can't get my head around how closure in R works

Tags: r

So I got this function inside another function:

```
power <- function(m){
  base <- function(x){
    x^m
  }
}
square <- power(2)
square(5) #25
```

I don't understand why this works. How I understand functions until this point doesn't seem to make sense here:, why I think it doesn't make sense is that when I assign power(2) to square, R is calling power (2), so in the environment of power, the value of m <- 2 is stored, but then I'm not calling any other function so it shouldn't do anything else. For instance, if I run power(2) no value is returned, as I expect, because there is no return value in its body, so I don't understand how R is assigning anything to square. When I run square, to see its body, I see that it is the same as base(x), I just don't understand how all of this is happening somebody help. Keep in mind that I'm fairly new to R, so please be understanding.

Comment: No one can explain it better than Hadley ;) see https://adv-r.hadley.nz/function-factories.html

Comment: Definitely read Hadley. The function `power` returns a function. Try running `(power(2))` and `(power(2))(5)`.

Comment: What I find interesting is that your example works. In my opinion, power should return NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For instance, if I run power(2) no value is returned

This isn't quite correct. A value *is* returned, but it is returned invisibly.

```r
power <- function(m){
  base <- function(x){
    x^m
  }
}
is.function(power(2))
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The reason this is a bit obscure in your example is that `<-` returns its RHS invisibly. Your example is equivalent to

```r
power <- function(m){
  base <- function(x){
    x^m
  }
  return(invisible(base))
}
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

A simpler example:

```r
just_two <- function(x) {
  z <- 2
}
just_two(5)  # invisible
just_two(5) == 2
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>